# Get SessionID via WebMethod from VB.NET to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, webmethod, sessionid, pagemethods

I'm a little clueless having the following code just not working:

Code-behind:

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)>
Public Shared Function GetSessionID() As String
    Dim sID = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID
    Debug.WriteLine(sID)
    Return sID
End Function
```

JavaScript:

```
var sID;

function init() {
    sID = PageMethods.GetSessionID();
...
```

The `sID` is obviously there and shown in debug output but in JavaScript `sID` holds "undefined" because the function returns "undefined" when executed in Firebug console. What's going on there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the `OnSuccess` callback of your `PageMethods` like this:

```
var sID;

function init() {
    PageMethods.GetSessionID(OnSuccess);
}

function OnSuccess(response, userContext, methodName) {
    sID = response;
    alert(sID);
}
```

References:

- [Exposing Web Services to Client Script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [Calling Web Services from Client Script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398995(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Yeah, that does the trick! I somehow never read anything about this on the MS Pages. Thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome. I couldn't find an official reference to add in the answer. It's probably buried somewhere in the infinite MSDN pages ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks OK. Where are you calling the function from? Try defining the variable inside the function:

```
function init() {
    var sID = PageMethods.GetSessionID();
}
```

---

If you are trying to read the sessionID why not just read directly from the cookie?

**JavaScript**

```
function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = escape(name) + '=',
    ca = document.cookie.split(';'),
    i = 0,
    c;
  for (i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') { c = c.substring(1, c.length); }
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) { return unescape(c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length)); }
  }
  return null;
}

var sID = readCookie('ASP.NET_SessionId');
```

Comment: same "undefined" behaviour when putting var into init(). init() is actually called from the _Default class in Default.aspx.vb and so far working well, because the rest of JS is executed as expected. Your Cookie example gives me "null" because thats what it returns. Cookies are actually no option. ill still give it a go to get it somehow working at first but using cookies cannot be the answer